# Changing the Approved/Pending/Rejected Heading

Tags: list, custom-list, versioning, approval-process

I've enabled Version Settings which means that submissions to a list can be approved/rejected or put pending as appropriate.

What i'm looking to do is change the Approved/Pending/Rejected name - I'd just like to change the Pending to "Submitted"

Is there anyway you can do this??